# Web service and client on different machine. .Net and JAVA

Tags: java, .net, web-services, webclient

I've created web services and their consuming web clients using C# and Java and they work on the same machine but I don't know how I can consume the services from a different machine. Does anyone know what steps I need to take or at least point me in the right direction?

This is an extract from my web-service. (.net)

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://deitel.com/", Description = "")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlDataReader dr;


    public WebService()
    {

        conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Owner-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=True");
    }

    [WebMethod(Description = "Insert Person into People table.")]
    public void insertPerson(long id, string name, string surname, int age, long contact, string location)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO People(ID, Name, Surname, Age, Contact, Location) VALUES ('" + id
            + "','" + name + "','" + surname + "','" + age + "','"+ contact + "','" + location + "')", conn);

        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: how are you consuming the web service from the client? by machine name or ip address? can you explain or show some code? if you did everything right and are using the web as channel, it should be as easy as changing an ip address or machine name in the configuration of the client...

Comment: I guess it qualifies as by machine name. It works if I try it out, but I don't know what the process is to make it available for a client on another machine.

Comment: Any idea? The client consuming it should be implemented with JAVA. I think it boils down to how the client is configured.

Comment: You'd need to post your client code